# plugin will not offer update even though a new version is available

Tags: plugin-development

I made a plugin, made revisions to it, and commited it again, yet in the admin area under plugins, I do not see under my plugin that an update is available.

So I had, say, version 1.2.0 , and now I made a new version 1.9.0 and I commited it, and on the wordpress site if you click the download button you WILL get the 1.9.0 version, but people that already have version 1.2.0 installed won't see an update option.

Also, on the wordpress site, it always says "Download version 1.0", even though the current version is 1.9.5 (that's what it says in the readme.txt under the stable tag)

How to fix this?

Comment: Did you Tag your version ? See more about Tagging [here](http://wordpress.org/plugins/about/svn/)

Comment: Yea, that's what surprising. If i didn't tag it i wouldn't be getting version 1.9.5 as the newest version on the wp site isn't it?

Comment: Yes you need to tag to get the new version listed

Comment: Tell us the URL, so we can take a look at it.

Comment: You do not understand me. I did all that and the new version IS listed. If you download my plugin now you WILL get the newest version, but if you had an older one installed already then you will not see an option to update, that is the problem.

Comment: @toscho http://wordpress.org/plugins/real-post-slider-lite/

Comment: I also believe it is weird that it always says "Download version 1.0", regardless of the stable tag version inside the readme.txt

Answer (score 0):

Changing the version number in your readme does not update the version with wordpress.org as an update. The plugins page is looking at this and not the tags in the repo. Take a look at 'tagging a new version' here: http://wordpress.org/plugins/about/svn/ - tag your new version and then give it some time. This will notify users of the update the next time their install checks for updates.